# Leader lines that only appear when labels is at a particular distance from point

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, leader-line

Is it possible to build an expression (or set the style) so that it will **not** generate a leader line when a label is within x-distance of a feature, but will generate a leader line when a label is greater than x-distance from a feature?

Basic leader line code I am using: 
`make_line(make_point($X,$Y),make_point("X","Y"))`

[image: leader lines]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you can use the `with_variable` function with an `if` conditional.
Basically you always create the line but you only return it from the expression if it is longer than your threshold.

Here I used a threshold of 10000 units:

```
with_variable(
    'line',
    make_line(
        make_point($x,$y),  -- the feature's geometry
        make_point("x","y")  -- the feature's label x and y value
    ),
    if(length(@line) > 10000, @line, NULL)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use QGIS 3.10 or later, which [supports leader lines natively](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/#feature-label-callouts).

You can adjust distances from feature and label as well as minimum line length (in mm, map units, etc) for rendering leader lines.

See [How to Add Leader Lines to Labels in QGIS 3.10](https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-add-leader-lines-to-labels-in-qgis-3-10/) for a step by step guide on how to enable leader lines.

---

Note that the minimum length of leader refers to the length of the depicted callout line - which is different to the actual distance between the label anchor coordinates (usually bottom left of label) and the geometry (and is what you are trying to control with geometry generator expressions).

With the inbuilt callouts the line will anchor to a sensible location around the label. It is the length of this line that is considered when setting a minimum length.

[image]

Comment: That is a much better answer! I didn't know.